# Reading a list of characters and storing in an array

Tags: c++, c

I am having issues with the following code and I cant figure out why out of loop is not being printed. With this code I want the program to ignore any spaces inputted by the user and after a space is inputted the number previously entered is stored in an array location. Like this I want 6 and 78 to be stored in 2 array locations not store them individually as 6 7 8.

This is my code:

```
while ((in=getchar()) != '0')
{
    if (in == ' ')
    {
        printf("space\n ");
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("assigning\n ");
        input[i]=in;
    }
    i++;
}
printf("Out of Loop");
```

My output when inputting 5 6 78 is:
assigning
space
assigning
space
assigning 
assigning
assigning

With this output I doubt whether 78 is being stored in one memory location.

I would really appreciate your help,Thankyou

Comment: Because you are never entering zero into the input stream. If you input "1 2 0" to your program then it should print "assigning space assigning space Out of Loop"

Comment: Please provide a [SSCE](http://www.sscce.org/) so we can understand what your intention is. Right now you are storing individual characters and this way you'll never store the string "78."

Comment: Also, you are always increasing the index, whether you stored something or left the initial indeterminate value. In addition, `getchar()` returns -1 on error, you are not checking for that.

Answer (score 2):

C++:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::string s;
int i;

std::getline( std::cin, s);         // read full line with whitespaces
std::istringstream iss( s);         // prepare to process the line
while( iss >> i) v.push_back( i);   // read into i and push into vector if 
                                    // operator>> was successful
```

C:

```
int array[ 10];
int i = 0, retval;

while( i < 10 && ( retval = scanf( "%d", &array[ i++])) == 1) ; 

if( i == 10) {
    // array full
}

if( retval == 0) {
    // read value not an integer. matching failure
}

if( retval == EOF) {
    // end of file reached or a read error occurred
}
```

Comment: If he doesn't want a c++ answer, he shouldn't tag his question with c++.

Answer (score 0):

You are deciding character by character. Thus, you will only store single digits or ignore those digits.

You could store the whole numbers like this (extending your code):

```
bool currentNumberStarted = false;
int currentNumber = 0;
int idx = 0;
while ((in=getchar()) != '0')// you probably want '\0' instead of '0'
{
    if (in == ' ')
    {
                    if (currentNumberStarted)
                    {
                        input[idx]=currentNumber;
                        idx++;
                        currentNumberStarted = false;
                    }
        printf("space\n ");
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("assigning\n ");
                    currentNumberStarted = true;
                    currentNumber *= 10;
        currentNumber += in;
    }
}
printf("Out of Loop");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I highly doubt that your while loop will ever end, even if you made that to  `'\0'` ,Because you are using `char` variable to store input. Not strings, Only strings uses `'\0'` at the end,How can we enter '\0' from keyboard..???. even if you want to keep it as `'0'`,you would alwasy have to enter 0 as last number to end the loop(which i think you dont want to.)

So the Solution is this:-

After Entering Numbers You will Hit ENTER key, which would generate a newline character '\n' so you have to check for new line character(`'\n'`), And as you are using getchar() function, it will returns EOF (-1) at the end of input, so its important to check for it too.So you have to check for both '\n' and EOF at once in while loop.And at last you should also check for array index number(it should be less than 1) in which you are storing numbers.

I made some effort to make you understand the program in comments.

```
int main()
{
  int i=0;
  int input[10]={0}; //here only 10 integers can be entered(hence i should be i<10)
  int in;     //To store input character
  int num=0;  //To store number which is converted from character.
  int new=1;  //To check if new number is started 0=false 1=True.
  int count=0;//This is just to know how many numbers entered,also used to print numbers at end.

  while ((in=getchar()) != '\n' && (in!=EOF) && i<10)//should check for both '\n' and EOF and array index also
  {
      if (in == ' ')
      {
         printf("space\n ");
         if(new==0) //if new Number is not started yet.
         {
            new=1;  //Start of a New number.(a number entered after space)
            i++;  //As new number is started it should be stored in new array index.
         }
         continue; //if space is entered just go to begining
      }
      else
      {
         printf("assigning\n ");
         num=in-48;  //converts a character to number (ex:- converts '3' to 3)
         input[i]=(input[i]*10)+num;  //storing the number..This is important do a paper work to understand this step.
         new=0;  //still in same number(we are still processing same number)
      }
  }
  printf("Out of Loop \n");

  count=i+1;  //This gives correct count of numbers entered

  for(i=0;i<count;i++)  //to print numbers.
     printf("%d ",input[i]);
return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:-**

E:>example.exe

**78 2 65 998 1**

assigning

assigning

space

assigning

space

.

.

.

space

assigning

Out of Loop

**78 2 65 998 1**